# problems of importing scipy module in python

Tags: python, scipy, dendrogram

there, I am a newbie of python 2.7. I have a quick question about importing modules. When doing hierarchical clustering I need a module named dendrogram. I saw the coding on the internet works well which has this line: "import from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage". However, when I changed this line to "import scipy" the code failed and the IDE displays "name linkage is not defined". Why only importing scipy does not work? Does module scipy include all modules such as dendrogram, linkage, etc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
```

dendogram and linkage functions are in the scipy.cluster.hierarchy module as can be seen in the [scipy.cluster.hierarchy reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html). This will make the dendrogam and linkage functions available in the current module you are writing.

If you only use:

```
import scipy
```

you will have to use the full name of the function like:

```
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage
```

Comment: Thank you brni！What is the relationship between scipy and scipy.cluster.hierarchy? I thought scipy includes the latter module, is it right?

Comment: scipy includes the module cluster, which includes the module hierarchy. The hierarchy module has functions called dendogram and linkage.